# Flag question to migrate to Photography?

Tags: discussion

I notice a some questions that might be better for Photography.  These might be a justified merge, or is it?  Do we feel this fits with the Astronomy part of Physics SE?

1. [Novice interested in buying a used telescope. What questions should I ask?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26535/novice-interested-in-buying-a-used-telescope-what-questions-should-i-ask)
2. [Telescopes to avoid as a beginner?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/telescopes-to-avoid-as-a-beginner)

This one I know would just be closed if it did get migrated:

[How do you clean a dusty lens?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24892/how-do-you-clean-a-dusty-lens)

Is my understanding correct that if you think it would be closed in another site, then it should just be closed as it stands?  I still find the review options confusing, since it seems that to "flag" something is to bring it up on meta, and the close options only give "off topic" as an option if it's too old to migrate.

Comment: I'm confused. What do (1) and (2) have to do with photography? It just seems to be about telescopes. Even if you consider optics a subset of photo.SE, the users over there are much more experienced with lenses than with mirrors. And the third question may very well get the *wrong* answers from photographers, since you shouldn't be cleaning most astronomical equipment as part of regular maintenance.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Well, meta is the place to take confusion.  Lots of telescope questions were appearing in the review, so this is the place to disseminate the status of them.  From your comment I take it that you see telescope questions belonging to this site.  Maybe they could be at home on either site.  Other people were voting to close these, so it's worth talking about and you might want to put in your 2 cents on the questions themselves.

Answer (score 2):

These questions were presumably on topic on Astronomy, and since we absorbed their scope, I think there is a solid argument to be made that they are on topic here. But the community can decide that they are off topic if desired - if enough people vote to close these questions, that effectively makes them off topic.

We don't actually have vote-to-migrate enabled on this site (except for migrating to meta I think), so if you think something is off topic, just close it. You can leave a comment saying that you think the question might be appropriate on e.g. Photography, and if it's closed by a moderator, we'll check the comments and decide to migrate if it's appropriate. We don't really have to decide on our end whether the question is actually on topic for the target site, since once it's migrated, they get to review it and if it's off topic for them, they just close it there.

By the way, to "flag" something means to actually cast a flag on it, not to bring it up on meta.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that photography.se will take them.

As documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130342/178438), when Astro.SE was getting closed they did a migration of astrophotography questions over to Photo.SE, and any posts that photo.se would accept were migrated off. Astro.SE didn't have that many posts, so I believe the posts were individually reviewed and migrated. These weren't migrated, so I don't think we can do it now.

Aside from that, (1) and (2) are Not Constructive anyway, so they shouldn't be migrated.

Aside from *that*, we *can't* migrate posts older than 60d.

---

Though if any new questions come up on astrophotography, I personally have no issue with allowing them as long as they don't have other issues (NC/NARQ/etc)

---

When you "flag" something, you click the "flag" button and choose an option (the flag gets forwarded to mods). Bringing stuff up on meta is fine, but if your flag can achieve it, then that's easier.

Comment: The options seem to imply that "off topic" isn't a valid reason to close, this is a source of some confusion.  If the justification is "Photo.SE wouldn't want them either" then that's saying it's both off topic and nonconstructive.  If it's off topic and only off topic then I guess it's just in your court.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @AlanSE: ? See, if a post is off topic, the we migrate if the destination site wants it, else we just close it on our side. Here, I'm saying that the posts fall within our scope (imo), but are NC so they get closed.

Comment: @AlanSE Why do you say the options imply that "off topic" isn't a valid reason to close? This might be something to ask another meta question about, not only so that you and anyone else who shares the same confusion can get it clarified, but so that the SE team can see how their site designs get interpreted in the real world and make them more clear if needed.